# Using map to process a list-of-objects in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to calculate the center-of-mass using the map function.  I don't want to use for loops.  Help with bottom two lines?

```
class Obj():  
    def __init__(self, mass = 0., x = 0., y = 0.):    
        self.mass = mass    
        self.x = x    
        self.y = y    

# Create List of Objects    
objList = []
n = 0    
for i in range(0,10):    
    for j in range(0,10):    
        objList.append(Obj(i*j,i,j))    

# Calculate Center of Mass of List
# The following is pseudocode, does not actually work
SumOfMass = sum(objList[:].mass)       
CenterOfMassX = sum(objList[:].x.*objList[:].mass)/SumOfMass
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do the last two lines unless you abandon your anti-`for` prejudice.

```
SumOfMass = sum(obj.mass for obj in objList)       
CenterOfMassX = sum(obj.x * obj.mass for obj in objList)/SumOfMass
```

With py2k (which are you using?), `map(func, alist)` is equivalent to `[func(v) for v in alist]` i.e. it returns a list. You need two scalar answers, not one or two vectors. What `func` did you have in mind? Why do you want to calculate the center of mass using the map function?

Comment: it returns a list in py2k only

Comment: right, in py3k you have to write list(map()) if you want a list ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
sumofmass = sum(i.mass for i in objList)
centre = sum(i.x * i.mass for i in objList)/sumofmass
```

also, you could populate your `objList` like this:

```
objList = [Obj(i*j, i, j) for in range(10) for j in range(10)]
```

Note, that `range` takes only integer arguments.

P.S. `map` **is** a `for` loop.

Comment: it's a for loop in py2k only. In py3k it's an iterator-maker.

Comment: `map` is a higher-level function.

Comment: @John: it's a for loop in a sense that it iterates over each element of the iterable.

Comment: So it's syntactically distinct from a for loop in that you have to pass functions to it rather than using a bound variable in an expression.

Comment: @intuited: why does it matter? that's not what my comment is about.

Comment: @SilentGhost: Well, it doesn't, necessarily.  But one reason people decide to avoid using for loops is in order to get more practice with thinking about things in terms of functions, and in using higher-level functions like `map`, `reduce`, etc.  So if this is the OP's reason for wanting to avoid for loops, then it is relevant.

Comment: @SilentGhost: NO, it makes an iterator (a map object) that does the iterating when you incite it ... it's a two-stage process, geddit??

Comment: @John: and it does iterating with the freaking `for` loop, not with some out-world magic. Geddit?

Comment: @John: and please there is no need to start a flame war, when **your answer clearly says that `map` returns a list**. Fix your answer first, please.

Comment: @SilentGhost: fixed my answer. Back to the point: """map is a for loop""" -- no, in py3k map() [that's the result of invoking map] is an iterator that performs a for loop when you ask it to. `it = map(func, stuff); results = list(it)`

Answer (score 2):

If you are really dead set against using `for`, you can use the [`attrgetter`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) function from the `operator` module.  E.G.:

```
from operator import attrgetter
mass_of = attrgetter('mass')
SumOfMass = sum(map(mass_of, objList))
```

However, doing so runs contrary to the dictates of Python style (as does using camelCase variables — normally you name them `like_this`).  It's more or less acceptable to use `map` if the thing you need to access is already in the form of a function which takes the sequence element as its only parameter.  In other words, if you can call `map(some_function, sequence)` without having to jump through any hoops like those above to get `some_function`, then it's okay.

For other situations (which is most of them), it's considered preferable or mandatory to use a [list-comprehension](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension) style as exemplified in some of the other answers.

Comment: `SumOfMass = map(mass_of, objList)` -- Looks like you're  missing a `sum()` sumwhere.